# Google Maps Annimation - App halting at polyline.Distance();

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation

I wonder if someone can help with my stalled Google Maps application.   I am adapting the animation features of one of the many examples are on the geocodezip, and mentioned in stackoverlow.  For example [Multiple Marker Animation](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleMarkerAnimation.html).  The general code for the startAnimation sequence looks like this.

```
function startAnimation(index) {
   if (timerHandle[index]) clearTimeout(timerHandle[index]);
   eol[index] = polyline[index].Distance();
   map.setCenter(polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0));

   poly2[index] = new google.maps.Polyline({
   path : [ polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0) ],
   strokeColor : "#FFFF00",
   strokeWeight : 3
   });
   timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate(" + index + ",50)", 2000); 
   // Allow    time for the initial map display
   currentDistance[index] = 50;
}
```

I have the example applications working properly but when embedded within my application the `startAnimation`  fails at the statement

```
 eol[index] = polyline[index].Distance();
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening.   I am presently climbing the steep learning curve that is Google Maps but looks like I am stuck on a ledge - can someone give me a lift up please?

Just for info, the index terms refer to the multiple markers and do not affect the behavior.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  Are you including the epoly third party library? That is where `.Distance()` comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes it is included (as per the example) it is based on.  Without including all the code (all the other features work) it is difficult to give you what you ask.  The only variation is that the javascript is moved into a java library so that in better integrates with my index.php other than that it is clean.  In situations like this, I am just looking for insights on how to isolate it.

Comment: Okay, it is resolved.  Many thanks for your comment it pushed me onto the right track.